# c++ error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error 'term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments' on the following line in my code:

```
steerToSpiralRefPoint(m_CentrePos);
```

But I'm not sure why this is... Is it that the function will only take 1 argument as a parameter, but since the 'm_centrePos' variable holds more than 1 attribute, the function is effectively receiving several parameters?

I have defined 'steerToSpiralRefPoint' with the line:

```
CDirectOverflyItem steerToSpiralRefPoint = new CDirectOverflyItem::SteerStep(const CHeloData aHeloData);
```

'm_CentrePos' has been assigned the value 'cCentrePos' at the start of this file ('cCentrePos' is a variable of type 'CCoordinate', which has a number of attributes- latitude, longitude, altitude, etc).

'CDirectOverflyItem's also has a number of attributes- ground speed, wind speed, wind angle, etc.

Can anyone point out to me why I'm getting this error, and how I should correct it?

Comment: What is the class definition of `CDirectOverflyItem`?

Comment: Does the `CDirectOverflyItem::SteerStep` provide an overloaded function call operator with one argument: `operator()(CCoordinate x)`?

Comment: The class definition of 'CDirectOverflyItem' is:  'class CDirectOverflyItem : public CSimpleSteeringItem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that I was trying to pass the wrong data type into the parameter- it was expecting a 'CHeloData', but I was trying to give it a 'CCoordinate'.

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
steerToSpiralRefPoint(m_CentrePos);
```

is a postfix expression of a function call. However as it follows from your post steerToSpiralRefPoint is not a function (or function pointer) but a pointer to an object. If you want to assign a value to the pointer then you have to write

```
steerToSpiralRefPoint = m_CentrePos;
```

Or if there is an operator function for this type then the code should look as

```
( *steerToSpiralRefPoint )( m_CentrePos );
```

And this construction

```
CDirectOverflyItem steerToSpiralRefPoint = new CDirectOverflyItem::SteerStep(const CHeloData );
```

is also invalid. You may not use qualifiers before variables in expressions. They may be used only in declarations.